# QT Application crash even with no code at all

Tags: qt, crash, windbg

I am developing an application in C++ with QT framework. After a point, i needed to use a debugger, and the story begin here.

I tried to setup CDB in QT Creator and i don't know if i changed anything in my code while doing that(probably not), and my app started to crash immediately after i run it.

I put "qDebug() << "TEST";" in the first line of the main function, it crashes without any output.

I just put a "return 1;" into the main, removed everything else, still crashed.

By the way, the debugger in Creator is not helping. It crashes too.

I moved my code into Visual Studio 2010, and the debugger stuck at "detach()" function of qvector.h file. After that it throw a message telling that :

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in app.exe. This may be due to corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in app.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded-. This may also be due to user pressing F12 while app.exe has focus. The output window may have more diagnostic information. [BREAK] [CONTINUE] [IGNORE]"

But there is an interesting point. If I click "Start Without Debugging" in VS2010, it runs with no problem.

Looking for a way out. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please, provide a code

Comment: Moved the whole code to a new project in Creator and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue related to QT, but rahter a "feature" while debugging in Visual Studio where the F12 button is mapped to trigger a breakpoint.

> The F12 key is reserved for use by the debugger at all times, so it should not be registered as a hot key. Even when you are not debugging an application, F12 is reserved in case a kernel-mode debugger or a just-in-time debugger is resident. 
>   [Source at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-VCAbO9fUY9I8hvee9c20XQ&tduid=%285a047c50c6d6b0971371f1676f8f9981%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-VCAbO9fUY9I8hvee9c20XQ%29%28%29&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way to disable the F12 shortcut.